# mongoose find document by subdocument's _id

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Let say I have the following structure:

```
var Partner = require('../partner/partner.model');

var ContractSchema = new Schema({
      // blahblah
      partners: [Partner.schema]
});
```

So here every contract has an array of partners, and each partner has an `_id` property.

I want to search for a contract, which has a partner with a specific `_id`.
I tried this, but didn't work:

```
  var ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;    
  Contract.find({
      partners: {
        $elemMatch: {
          _id: {
            $eq: new ObjectId(req.query.partnerId)
          }
        }
      }
    }, function (err, serviceContracts) {
      if (err) {
        return handleError(res, err);
      } else {
        return res.status(200).json(serviceContracts);
      }
    });
```

**EDIT:** Here's an example what I have in the db:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57e370e72beac9fc21c99ca3"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2016-09-22T05:49:27.000Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-09-22T05:49:27.000Z"),
    "currency" : "USD",
    "partners" : [ 
        {
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2016-09-22T05:49:27.000Z"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-09-22T05:49:27.000Z"),
            "name" : "Apple Inc.",
            "_id" : ObjectId("57e370e72beac9fc21c99caa")
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Comment: first of all replace ```Contract.find({
      partner: {``` with ```Contract.find({
      partners: {```  Then tell

Comment: Replaced, still not works.

Comment: Can you please give me your  one record  contract table.

Comment: @Himanshusharma Added an example.

Comment: this works directly in mongo db.a.find({partners:{$elemMatch:{_id:{$eq:ObjectId("57e370e72beac9fc21c99caa")}}}}), you're sure that req.query.partnerId is correct ? Have you tried using directly : _id: req.query.partnerId ?

Comment: `Contract.find({ 'partners._id' : req.query.partnerId })`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As @robertklep said, this is working:

```
Contract.find({ "partners._id": req.query.partnerId})
  .then(function(contracts) {
    return res.status(200).json(contracts);
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    return handleError(res, err);
  });
```